# MySQL join on row number (first with first, second with second etc)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, row-number

Let's say I have 2 simple tables

```
Table t1    Table t2
+------+    +------+
| i    |    | j    |
+------+    +------+
|   42 |    |    a |
|    1 |    |    b |
|    5 |    |    c |
+------+    +------+
```

How can I have an output of the 2 tables, joined without any condition except the row number?

I would like to avoid the creation of another index if possible.

I am using MySQL 5.7

---

With this example, the output would be :

```
Table output
+------+------+
| i    | j    |
+------+------+
|   42 |    a |
|    1 |    b |
|    5 |    c |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972320/how-to-do-an-inner-join-on-row-number-in-sql-server?

Comment: The order you perceive in your tables is not really there, and you need to give us logic for why the value 42 should be associated with `a` versus any other letter in the second table.  SQL tables are based on _unordered_ sets.

Comment: I think this answer would be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836566/sql-join-two-tables-with-specific-condition

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Let's say I ran an order by on this tables before the JOIN

Comment: ...which would have zero effect, because again, tables have no internal order.

Comment: Rows in relational databases represent unordered sets, so you're out of luck.

Comment: Even if table i and j are subqueries (containing order by)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask *can* be done, assuming that your comment is true;

> "Even if table i and j are subqueries (containing order by)?"

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 ( i INT );
CREATE TABLE table_2 ( j VARCHAR(4) );

INSERT INTO table_1
VALUES (3),(5),(1);

INSERT INTO table_2
VALUES ('c'), ('b'),('a');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.i, t2.j
FROM (SELECT t1.i
           , @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rownum
      FROM (SELECT table_1.i
            FROM table_1
            ORDER BY ?) t1
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) v) t1
         JOIN (SELECT t2.j
                    , @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum
               FROM (SELECT table_2.j
                     FROM table_2
                     ORDER BY ?) t2
                        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) v) t2 ON t2.rownum = t1.rownum;
```

---

However, this approach is a) not efficient, and b) indicative of questionable design. You probably want to look for something that actually relates your two tables or, if nothing exists, create something. If there is really nothing that relates the two tables, then you'll have trouble with the `ORDER BY` clauses anyway.

Comment: I tried your query using  `t1.i` and `t2.j` instead of the `?`, but it didn't worked, I have the error `Every derived table must have its own alias`. How can I fix it please? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=59acaf529344ab8219a4785f33ff61e8

Comment: @txemsukr that's correct, each subquery must have an alias. I've updated my answer with that fixed. Here's an example of it running with arbitrary ORDER BY clauses. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jeRcABZm4Yu6gRHKDdEneT/0

Answer (score 1):

If the tables do not necessarily have the same number of rows, then use `union all` and `group by` -- along with variables:

```
select max(t.i) as i, max(t.j) as j
from ((select (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as seqnum, t1.i
       from t1 cross join
            (select @rn1 := 0) params
      ) union all
      (select (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum, t2.j
       from t2 cross join
            (select @rn2 := 0) params
      ) 
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Note:  The results in each column are in an *arbitrary* and *indeterminate* order.  The order might vary on different runs on the query.

You don't provide enough information to ensure the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
select t1.i,t2.j
from
    (SELECT i,@row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num FROM t1, (SELECT @row_num:= 0) AS sl) t1
join
    (SELECT j,@row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num FROM t2, (SELECT @row_num:= 0) AS sl) t2
on  t1.row_num=t2.row_num
```

Comment: This won't generate the expected output.

Comment: In the absence of any ORDER BY clause, it's nonsensical to use variables in this way. It's roughly equivalent to owning a broken clock, but only consulting it at roughly the same time every day.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it